# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}2^jz^{j^2}$ using Cauchy-Hadamard formula: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

For a power series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j(z-z_0)^j$ the Cauchy-Hadamard formula states that:$$R=\frac{1}{\operatorname{lim sup}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$
Where $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ is a sequence formed from the set of coefficients $\{a_j\}$ and R is the radius of convergence (ROC).

When I'm trying to apply this to find the ROC for $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}2^jz^{j^2}$ i get the following:
$$\{a_j\}=1,2,4,... \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 1^{\frac10},2^{\frac11},4^{\frac12}...=1,2,2...$$
From which i deduce that $R=\frac12$ but the book says the answer is $R=1$.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm also curious as to why $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}2^jz^{j^2}$ can be called a power series.

The book I'm using is Fundamentals of Complex Analysis by Saff & Snider, section 5.4 exercise 3(b).

Comment: This is because here $a_n=\left\{\begin{matrix}2^j,&n=j^2\text{ for }j\in\mathbb{N}\\0,&\text{Otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$, and not $a_n=2^n$.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: And I also realized why it can be called a power series.